# How Can I Query the Parent Record Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, office365api

[Click here for picture Overview of the classes/entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/129SV.png)

Hi guys, It could be great if someone could re-code and help me on this.I am new in D365 and JS. Basically, how can I query the parent to case_adjustment from adjustment invoice record using JS. I have provide my current code, please help me to review it. I have try everything but so far no luck. Sorry for my unprofessional picture. But I hope you understand it and could help me to code for this situation.

I have try to enable the debugger and it shows that the code cant run the adjustmentTypeLookup. and thats why it cant pass the value to retrieveRecord .Thank you.

```js
function adjustmentInvoiceApproveAmount(executionContext) {
    try {
        // Get the form context
        const formContext = executionContext.getFormContext();

        // Extract attribute values from the form
        const adjustmentAmount = formContext.getAttribute("case_adjustmentamount").getValue();
        const amountDue = formContext.getAttribute("case_amountdue").getValue();
        const adjustmentTypeLookup = formContext.getAttribute("case_adjustmenttype").getValue();

        // Exit as adjustmenttype is not set
        if (!adjustmentTypeLookup) return;

        // Extract the adjustment type record ID from the payment type lookup
        const adjustmentTypeId = adjustmentTypeLookup[0].id.substring(1, 37);
        //console.log("GUID \"case_adjustmenttype\" = " + adjustmentTypeId + " ; " + typeof adjustmentTypeId);
        //console.log(adjustmentTypeId);
         
        // Retrieve a SINGLE case_adjustmenttype based on lookup ID on form
        Xrm.WebApi.retrieveRecord("case_adjustmenttype", adjustmentTypeId, "$select=case_name").then(
            function success(adjustmentType)
          {
                // If the payment type is credit notes then check payment amount and resit amount
                if (adjustmentType.case_name.toLowerCase() == "Credit notes".toLowerCase()) 
                {
                    if (adjustmentAmount >= amountDue) {
                        formContext.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
                        Xrm.Navigation.openErrorDialog({message:"Payment Amount cannot be more than Resit Amount."})
                    }
                }
                //Otherwise do nothing
            },
            function (error) 
            {
                console.log(error.message);
            }
        );
    } 
    catch (error) 
    {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are struggling with the code of retrieving data using web API, I would suggest checking out "CRM REST Builder".

https://github.com/jlattimer/CRMRESTBuilder

Import the solution and refresh the solutions page in dynamics which will show up the button to start this tool. This tool is awesome at generating code for different scenarios.